# Magento Administration Configuration Page blank after upgrade to 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, upgrade, fatal-error

I have seen many similar posts describing the problem I am experiencing, but I have been so far entirely unsuccessful in trying to resolve it. I recently upgraded to Magento CE 1.9.1.0, and now I get a blank page when navigating to System > Configuration in the back-end. The rendered page contains only empty html and body tags.

#### The error:

The only error that I get (in the logs or on screen with `display_errors` enabled in the `index.php`) when opening the configuration page (or any other admin page) is the following:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method `Zend_Locale::getAlias()` in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php on line 243

Referer: http://example.com/index.php/magento/index/index/key/.../

The relevant line from `Locale.php` is:

```
$allowedAliases[Zend_Locale::getAlias($code)] = $code;
```

#### I have attempted:

- Refreshing and/or disabling all caches.
- Disabling all non-Mage modules in `app/etc/local.xml` (`disable_local_modules`), `app/etc/modules` (`<active>false</active>`), `app/code/local` and `app/code/community` (removing all files).
- Tried both PHP 5.4.16 and 5.5.21
- Comparing all files in `app/` and `lib/` with those from a fresh install. None were missing, but I attempted refreshing them anyway.
- Refreshing the user permissions by opening and saving the Administrator role in System > Permissions > Roles.
- Checked and re-checked file permissions, having tried both the Magento recommended perms and fully permissive (777).

#### System specs:

- CentOS 7
- Magento CE 1.9.1.0
- PHP 5.4.16 or 5.5.21

Comment: Sounds like one of the core setup scripts fails to complete. Install n98-magerun and run its `sys:setup:incremental`, while configuration cache is clean but active.

Comment: What an excellent toolkit. I activated and cleaned all caches. `sys:check` gives a clean bill of health. `sys:setup:incremental` produced the following output: Found 68 configured setup resource(s) / Found 0 setup resource(s) which need an update. After that I restarted apache, but the problem persists.

Comment: Is your head section filled in the source? I find it rather odd that body is empty, but had a closing body and html tag. Is that not the browser reformatting what is really zero sized response? And if it is, what is the response status? 50x? And what value for the x? ;-)

Comment: The HTML head tag is present, but empty. Digging some more through the HTTP headers has revealed a `500 Internal Server Error` from which I infer that the browser is receiving no content at all from Magento. The only error that is evident in the logs is the persistent Locale.php one.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. You'll only catch this if you manage to get error logging enabled in php. Also, any Ioncube involved here?

Comment: With `display_errors` enabled in the index.php, the configuration page displays the same error that I'm seeing in the logs: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Locale::getAlias() in .../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php on line 243`. The relevant line from Locale.php is `$allowedAliases[Zend_Locale::getAlias($code)] = $code;`

Comment: Ioncube is not enabled. I tried enabling it on the chance that a legacy extension might require it, but the issue persists with ot without ioncube.

Comment: How did you disable the modules? Did you rename or remove the xml in the app/etc/modules directory ?

Comment: I tried disabling all non-Mage modules globally using `disable_local_modules` in app/etc/local.xml. I also tried disabling individual modules via the `active` parameter in their respective XML configs, and I tried removing all non-Mage files/folders from app/etc/modules, app/code/local and app/code/community.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same message after upgrading from 1.9.0 -> 1.9.1. Problem was fixed by reinstalling Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.7.0 via Magento Connect Manager.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. And this answer worked for me.

> I got the same message after upgrading from 1.9.0 -> 1.9.1. Problem was fixed by reinstalling Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.7.0 via Magento Connect Manager.

But the reason why it happend was because Magento turned off SSLv3 on Magento Connect. The solution for that is found here [Magento 1.9.2 Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73748/magento-1-9-2-unknown-cipher-in-list-tlsv1)
In file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php I changed the code

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1'); 
to
if(isset($var)){
   $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
}
```

Only after this change could the last updates be done. In my clients case there where 4 core files not updated.